# How to combine multiple thirdparty POJO into single POJO

Tags: java

We have multiple third party pojo which we wan to combine into single pojo and use that single pojo to map to a JSON using jackson.

third party pojo -

```
public class ThirdPartyPojo1 {

    private String random1

    //public setters and getters

}
```

```
public class ThirdPartyPojo2 {

    private String random2

    //public setters and getters

}
```

we wan to combine these to form a single pojo like -

```
public class ourPojo {
     private String random1;
     private String random2;

     //public setters and getters
}
```

we will use jackon to serialize this into a JSON string. How can we achieve this?

Comment: How would you *want to* handle conflicts?

Comment: @ScottHunter can you clarify, what do you mean by that?

Comment: What if they have any fields in common?  Worse, what if they have fields with the same name but different types?

Comment: When you write "POJO", do you mean "DTO"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Fields are unique.

Comment: @knittl yes you can say its a DTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my way to solve your question. I am not sure if it has better solution so you may take this as a reference. I use ObjectReader readerForUpdating() to merge multiple json sources but this is limited to shallow copy. You may need another way to do with more complicated object. Here is my code:

```
package jackson;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;

public class Test {

    static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create instance and convert it to json
        ThirdPartyPojo1 obj1 = new ThirdPartyPojo1();
        obj1.setRandom1("value 1");
        String json1 = toJson(obj1);
        
        // Create instance and convert it to json
        ThirdPartyPojo2 obj2 = new ThirdPartyPojo2();
        obj2.setRandom2("value 2");
        String json2 = toJson(obj2);
        
        // Suppose the field names of ThirdPartyPojo are corresponding to ourPojo
        // Firstly, use ObjectMapper readValue() to get ThirdPartyPojo1 field i.e. random1 
        ourPojo obj3 = mapper.readValue(json1, ourPojo.class);
        
        // Secondly, use ObjectReader to update ourPojo object
        // Notes that it makes shallow copy only
        ObjectReader updater = mapper.readerForUpdating(obj3);
        // Update ourPojo from ThirdPartyPojo2 field i.e. random2
        obj3 = updater.readValue(json2);
        
        // The result displays a merging json from your single POJO
        System.out.println(toJson(obj3));
    }
    
    static String toJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    }

}

class ThirdPartyPojo1 {
    private String random1;
    // public setters and getters
}

class ThirdPartyPojo2 {
    private String random2;
    // public setters and getters
}

class ourPojo {
    private String random1;
    private String random2;
    //public setters and getters
}
```

Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```